# KRaft design architecture - Separation of Controllers and Brokers

Tags: apache-kafka, kraft

We want to install *Kafka Kraft cluster* on 35 machines ( machines are DELL physical machines - type R760 And OS is Linux RHEL 8.6 version )

Since we are dealing with **Kafka production cluster** , we want to understand what is the best Practice and the right approach to install the machines and configuration

The question about the cluster that we are preparing is about the **controllers**

Do we need to set and install the controllers on **dedicated machines** and not on Kafka machines itself?

for example I gives here **PLAN1** and **PLAN2**

**PLAN1**

We can install 3 controllers on the first 3 Kafka machines ( means both PID's are running on Kafka machine as broker pid and controller pid     [ *pid - Linux process id* ]

kafka1-3 will include `pid` for broker and `pid` for controller

kafka4+ will include only `pid` for broker

[image]

**PLAN2**

We can install 3 controllers on different dedicated machines

35 physical machines for Kafka Kraft service

3 dedicated VM machines for Kafka controllers ( VM machines since from our understanding controllers are not consume so much resources )

[image]

**The second question** , is about how many controllers services we need?

Is it always 3 controllers for *3 Kafka machines* or for *15 Kafka machines* or for *35 Kafka machines* ?

Comment: This looks more like a question on deployment strategy rather than _programming_, so is outside the scope of Stack Overflow.  Perhaps see if it's appropriate over on [swe.se]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about it like this - Raft is a leader election protocol. If you lost 1/3 of the nodes; you're left with 2 equal "electors" who may not agree on a decision.

So, having more controllers is better for quorum, but you generally don't need more than 5 or 7 (odd numbers recommended). This didn't really change from Zookeeper or Kraft...

Two "pid" on any node isn't what you want. `process.roles` accepts both roles of broker and controller, and would run as a single Java process. You can also separate them, and ultimately is determined by if you have the hardware available and how many nodes you're willing to lose

Comment: about what you wrote - "Two "pid" on any node isn't what you want" you means that kfka broker machine will have one PID that include both - broker service and controller  ??

Comment: Yes. Test it locally by starting Kafka with that setting

Comment: in any case form your ( great ) answer we understand that preferred solution i to set the controllers on different machines as my PLAN2 , am I right ?

Comment: Separate machines would be recommended yes, but they don't need to be identical hardware as the brokers, per my understanding.